# Анимация на JS. Эффект курсора мышки

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Всем здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать такую анимацию на сайте, как на скриншоте: http://prntscr.com/p4tzv3 
Что бы когда водишь мышкой, область возле курсора убирала затемнение области сайта.
Или хотя бы в какую сторону копать. 
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: вот тут похожая тема https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwSBO8a_MXs&t=1060s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как-то так?

```js
addEventListener('mousemove', e => 
  document.body.style.setProperty('--xy', e.x + 'px ' + e.y + 'px'))
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  --xy: -150px -150px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at var(--xy), #0000, #000f 30vh),
              url(https://picsum.photos/id/34/1000/1000);
}
```

Comment: Как то - да :) Спасибо большое :)